# PhpStorm Startup task - php artisan serve

Tags: php, task, phpstorm, startup

I am working with a project locally and I want to run "php artisan serve" with the PhpStorm's startup task feature every time I start the project.

I went to **Settings -> Tools -> Startup Tasks** and clicked the green plus, then **Add New Configuration**. However, I don't know what to choose from there. There is no "artisan" option there.

How should I do it?

Comment: "Startup task" is an ordinary instance of Run/Debug Configuration. If you can execute your desired command using Run Configuration then there is no problem. Possible Run Configuration types I can think of: PHP Script, NPM Script, Gulp or Grunt task.

Comment: I would like to run specifically "php artisan serve", but I can't see an "artisan" option. For gulp watch, I used the "gulp" option and then just added watch.

Comment: That's because PhpStorm does not support *framework specific tools* at Run Configurations level; hence no *dedicated support* for artisan commands. You either have to use what's available (generic stuff) .. or maybe find some plugin that provides such specific Run Configuration (I personally does not know such plugin).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Artisan is a **php script** so you can simply add a new **PHP Script** task:

File: Browse to you project directory and select **artisan**.

Arguments: serve

If your php interpreter is setup correctly in your PHPStorm settings, then you will be able run this task and it will automatically run at startup.

Comment: Where do I add this PHP task?

Answer (score 14):

> Where do I add this PHP task? – Brad

### phpstorm  > 2020.3

- File:

`path/to/artisan`

Usually is at root directory of the Laravel project.

- Arguments:

`serve`

[image]

### Older Version of PHP | phpstorm 2017.2 <

`File -> Settings... -> Tools -> Startup Tasks -> +(Add) -> PHP Script`

Name: serve

Single instance only - checked

Comment: You can simply do it with `edit configuration` right?

Comment: Choose the installed PHP as interpreter. Also, you can choose the local artisan file within your project as the configuration file.