# PhpStorm: run php artisan serve Undefined index: REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-artisan, serve

I want to use `php artisan serve` as a Run Configuration in PhpStorm and already set it up like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587559/phpstorm-startup-task-php-artisan-serve).

When I run the command / configuration (?), the server seems to start but then is instantly stopped.
This is my console output:

```
C:\dev\php\php_7.2\php-win.exe C:\Users\bendi\PhpstormProjects\dashboard\artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>

Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in C:\Users\bendi\PhpstormProjects\dashboard\server.php on line 11
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in C:\Users\bendi\PhpstormProjects\dashboard\server.php on line 11

Process finished with exit code 0
```

A simple `php artisan serve` in the console works normally.

EDIT: I think it isn't a duplicate because the problem hasn't anything to do with the php code (at least I think so). As stated earlier, the normal command works.

EDIT 2: [my run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg6HW.png)

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you've set-up your run configuration? When I follow the instructions in the linked question I can't reproduce this problem at all.

Comment: @apokryfos I just added a screenshot of my run configuration to my question. I don't think I did anything different to the linked question.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the Interpreter? In the linked question there is something about "If your php interpreter is setup correctly in your PHPStorm settings".

Comment: `serve` uses the internal [PHP development server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) with `server.php` being the configured router file. If you instantly get the `REQUEST_URI` error then that indicates that something got short-circuited somwhere and is executing `server.php` on the CLI instead of when a request comes in. Not sure where that might be happening but that's my hypothesis in case it helps in investigating.

Comment: `C:\dev\php\php_7.2\php-win.exe ` .... --- please use **php.exe** instead of **php-win.exe** in your PHP Interpreter settings.

Comment: @LazyOne it works, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LazyOne pointed out, I simply had to change the CLI Interpreter in **Languages & Frameworks > PHP > CLI Interpreter > PHP executable** from `php-win.exe` to `php.exe`. Now everything works as wished.